# How to perform DML(Update, Insert, Delete) operations on google spanner from a java application?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Need your help!

I am trying to perform DML operation using a driver class(com.simba.cloudspanner.core.jdbc42.CloudSpanner42Driver), but I am getting exception like

```
"Caused by: shaded.com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: DML statements(INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE) are not supported."
```

**But SELECT query is working fine**. Below is my java code.

Please let me know how can I perform DML operations on spanner from a java app.

I  tried `Mutation.newInsertBuilder` , `Mutation.newUpdateBuilder`, `Mutation.delete` to achieve DML operations using `com.google.cloud.spanner.Mutation; libraries`, **but** I am actually looking for some kind of implementation where user can run SQL statements to do DML operations.

```
public class SimbuDriverInsert {

   static final  String CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:cloudspanner://localhost;Project=optimistic-leaf-197820;Instance=testspanner01;Database=students;PvtKeyPath=C:\\MuleWorkspace\\test-driver\\src\\main\\resources\\gcloudPrivateKey.json";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{
      Class.forName("com.simba.cloudspanner.core.jdbc42.CloudSpanner42Driver");
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL);
      stmt = conn.createStatement();


      String sql = "INSERT INTO studentdetails (id,age,name) " +
              "VALUES (100, 30, 'Ali')";
       stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
       System.out.println("Inserted record into the table...");
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}//end main

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official JDBC driver supplied by Oracle (together with Simba) does not support DML and DDL statements. [This open source driver does support both](https://github.com/olavloite/spanner-jdbc). If you include this driver in you project and change the following line

`Class.forName("com.simba.cloudspanner.core.jdbc42.CloudSpanner42Driver");`

into

`Class.forName("nl.topicus.jdbc.CloudSpannerDriver");`

the code should work. The driver uses the same URL syntax as the official driver, but also adds a number of extra possibilities. [Have a look at the Wiki page](https://github.com/olavloite/spanner-jdbc/wiki) of the driver for more information.

The driver can be added as a maven dependency or [downloaded from the releases page of the project](https://github.com/olavloite/spanner-jdbc/releases).

Have a look here for more examples on how to use the driver: http://www.googlecloudspanner.com/ with different frameworks and tools.

Comment: Hi Knut Olav Loite, glad i received response from you :)

I tried with Class.forName("nl.topicus.jdbc.CloudSpannerDriver"); too. But i am getting below exception :: 
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException
 at nl.topicus.jdbc.statement.CloudSpannerStatement.executeUpdate(CloudSpannerStatement.java:579).

And, my query was very simple like "UPDATE studentdetails SET   age = 99, name = 'Alibaba'  WHERE id =100"

Comment: It looks like you are calling Statement#executeUpdate(String sql, int autoGeneratedKeys); instead of Statement#executeUpdate(String sql);. The former is not supported, as Google Cloud Spanner does not support any auto generated keys. If you call executeUpdate with only the SQL-string, you should not be getting this error.